# .NETフレームワーク内部のプロファイリング

Tags: c#, .net

VS2010 Ultimate のプロファイリング機能や DevPartner のパフォーマンス分析機能を利用して、ボトルネックを探しているのですが、.NETフレームワーク内で時間を要しているように見えます。

そのような場合に.NETフレームワーク内のどこで時間を要しているのかを調べる良い方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VS2010: Just My Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/profiler/2011/05/13/vs2010-just-my-code/)で解説されていますが、ライブラリコードを表示してしまうと見え辛くなってしまうため、既定ではMy Codeのみが表示されるようになっています。Summaryページ右上の「Show All Code」をクリックすればフレームワークを含むすべてのコードを確認することができますし、オプションの設定でデフォルトの動作を変更することもできます。