# IMETIP.DLLとWPF TextBoxの関係

Tags: c#, wpf

[この質問の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29326/net%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0)に従って、プロファイリング結果を確認すると IMETIP.DLLで時間を使っているように見えるのですが、どのような要因が考えられますでしょうか。

GridにTextBoxをaddしているだけなのですが…。

Comment: imetip.dll は文字通り日本語 MS-IME の一部です。そこで時間を食っているのであれば、ATOK や Google 日本語入力に切り替える等で imetip.dll を使わなくなる＝速度向上すると思われます。

Comment: ですよね。imeを変更して試したいところなのですが…環境の変更が許されないもので。ただ、変更して傾向だけでも見たいところなのですが。

Comment: Active Directory が禁じているとかシステム管理者が禁止しているとかなら、交渉してみましょう。ウチでも「デバッグのため」なら結構融通利かせてくれますよ。（まあ VirtualBox 等で仮想環境作っちゃうほうが簡単ですけど）

Comment: まぁ、色々あって環境が石器時代になってしまった経緯があり、ソフト開発している会社とは思えない状態なんですよね。